# Using multiple-class selectors in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I know IE7 & IE8 supposedly have support for using multiple CSS class selectors, but I can't seem to get it to work.

CSS:

```
.column {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}
.two.column {
  width: 140px;
}
.three.column {
  width: 220px;
}
.four.column {
  width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='two column'>Two Columns</div>
<div class='three column'>Three Columns</div>
<div class='four column'>Four Columns</div>
```

It always end up using the *.four.column* rule. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You want to make sure and use a doc type so you do not render in quirks mode. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
.column {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.two.column {
  width: 140px;
}
.three.column {
  width: 220px;
}
.four.column {
  width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="two column">Two Columns</div>
<div class="three column">Three Columns</div>
<div class="four column">Four Columns</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Crap, that was really careless of me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How to get out from quirks mode and why you get in there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7176341/1806628

Answer (score 3):

Not that you're necessarily doing anything wrong, but if you just have classes like:

```
.column {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}
.two {
  width: 140px;
}
.three {
  width: 220px;
}
.four {
  width: 300px;
}
```

Then you should still get the rendering you want when you apply those classes in the right order:

```
<div class='column two'>Two Columns</div>
```

If you think of the css classes being like programming classes, the `.two` class extends the base `.column` class, over-riding its width property.

This way, you can also apply your `.two`, `.three` and `.four` classes to other page elements whose width you want to fix to those sizes, without having to be reliant on their position or container on the page.