# CSS sprite button in IE8 doesn't show/work?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am having an issue with ie8 and a simple form submit button. I use an image as a button with a bit of CSS so it has a nice hover effect. But it doesn't work/show up in IE8.

`btnSubmit.png` has the default and hover state.

this is my code

```
<input name="form_submit" id="form_submit" 
    class="btns btnFormsubmit" type="submit"  />
```

and CSS

```
.btns {
    background-color:transparent;
    background-position:left bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:0 none;
    display:block;
    height:31px;
    text-indent:-3999em;
    }
.btns:hover {
    background-position:left top;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.btnFormsubmit {
    background-image:url(imgs/btnSubimt.png);
    height: 31px;
    width:267px !important;
}
```

I also tried to add `href="#"`

```
<input href="#" name="form_submit" id="form_submit" 
    class="btns btnFormsubmit" type="submit"  />
```

Comment: Not sure, but it could be a doctype issue...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671178/using-multiple-class-selectors-in-ie7-and-ie8

Comment: Are you sure you only misspelled `url(imgs/btnSubimt.png);` here?

Comment: @bazmegakapa, just misspelled it here on stackoverflow, going to check the doctype tip.  ps: thx for editing my code message

Comment: hmm, i have the input:hover working, i also added ` font-size: 0;
  display:block;
  line-height: 0;` but when i point my iframe src to the file it doesn't show the button image at all???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not support input:hover css selector in quirks mode. Try adding a doctype declaration (like for instance `<!DOCTYPE html>`) and it should be OK.

Comment: hmm, i have the input:hover working, i also added ` font-size: 0;
  display:block;
  line-height: 0;` but when i point my iframe src to the file it doesn't show the button image at all???

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Do you mean that the image is not shown when your page is placed in an iframe on another page?

Answer (score 0):

Inputs are hard to style consistently across different browsers. I would recommend using a `<button type="submit"></button>` if you can't get it to work (if the doctype is not the issue as suggested before).