# Page stuck in Quirks Mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, doctype, quirks-mode

Currently the page I am working displays fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE9 it is rendering in Quirks mode.

Looking into the issue further, it seems that

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
```

is always getting commented out.  Causing Quirks mode to stay in place as no doctype is specified.  Basically, I am trying to force the page to render in normal IE9 and not quirks mode.  However, something is causing the comment out.  Regretfully, this is a wordpress theme that's why I am having a hard time fixing the issue as I didn't write the original code.

Anyone have suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: regretfully I do not as the page is password protected as its in currently in development.  Any ideas of what to look for without seeing the page is question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "[the doctype] is always getting commented out".

There are many different things that can cause Quirks Mode, [see here](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8modes).

Another common cause is having [stuff before the doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes). Even [invisible stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168612/divs-appearing-different-on-different-browsers/6168758#6168758).

You can fix this without debugging the actual problem if you add this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Recent versions of IE are known to comment out the doctype line for some bizarre reason.

Comment: @BoltClock: Do you have any more info about that?

Comment: Not sure about sources, but a significant number of people here have run into this problem. I don't know much about it either myself.

Comment: Thanks thirtydot.  I was able to fix the problem somewhat by using
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

However, your fix worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: But XHTML 1.0 Strict requires the xml header before the doctype! So your answer is a winner, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also check your IE,

1. Click on Tools
2. Compatibility view settings
3. Be sure your site is not included in the "compatibility view" aka quirks
4. See also the check boxes