# DIV overflow hidden and height not working in DOCTYPE HTML standards mode in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a `<div>` with overflow:hidden, and `height:100%` which displays the div contents on the screen and fits to the height of the window.

This works with Chrome, and Safari.

IE9, doesn't respect my div `overflow:hidden` and `height:100%` so it just expands the div to display the content.

On my page I have the following doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

This should indicate the compliance with the latest standards.

If I remove the Doctype completely then everything works fine in all the browsers, except the fonts are too big because there isn't a doctype specified.

Any reason this might be happening?
html and body tags are specified as height:100% in css stylesheet

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:100%">
content too tall to fit height of the screen, so a scroll bar is added.  In IE9 it doesn't work because it just extends the height of the DIV
</div>
```

Edit: 
I have included full HTML that can completely replicate the problem in IE9

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <style>
      * { /* Resetting the defaults */
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }

      html, body { /* Assigning Height To Containers First */
          height: 100%;
      }

      table
      {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        border-collapse: collapse  
      }

      .headerRow
      {
        height:50px;
      }

      .sidePanelTd
      {


      }

      .sidePanelDiv
      {
        overflow:auto;
        height:100%;
      }

      .row2
      {

      }

     </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:White;overflow:auto">
    <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 id="mainTable">
    <tr class="headerRow">
        <td valign=top colspan=2>Header
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row2">
        <td>
        td 1
        </td>

        <td class="sidePanelTd">
           <div class="sidePanelDiv">
              td 2 content <br>too <br>tall <br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>to fit height of the screen, 
              so a scroll bar is added.  In IE9 it doesn't work because it just extends 
              the height of the DIV
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we see a fiddle? That might help us solve your problem!

Comment: @user1060500: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Ok Milche, thanks for pointing out this (technical) mistake which adds absolutely no value to what we're trying to solve here.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've tried and it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <style>
      * { /* Resetting the defaults */
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }

      html, body { /* Assigning Height To Containers First */
          height: 100%;
      }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="overflow:hidden;height:100%">
      content <br>too <br>tall <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>to fit height of the screen, 
      so a scroll bar is added.  In IE9 it doesn't work because it just extends 
      the height of the DIV
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**As you commented, you should add this**

```
table, tr, td {
    height: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  The only difference I have really is that I have a table with height:100% and tr with height:100% that the div is inside.  Could the problem be the table?

Comment: Ok, I'm working on replicating your solution and then comparing any differences with what I have.  I will let you know as my HTML is a little more complex, but the basics are the same.

Comment: Ok, I can replicate the problem.  I revised my question to include source HTML to replicate based on your example.  One difference you'll see is that there are two TR's in my example with the first one being a header tr.  What do you think?

Comment: @user1060500 Nah, don't write inline styles, `border-collapse` property is for table and not tr, so just copy paste that between style tags

Comment: I know, but sometimes when I am playing with a layout I start with inline and then move to css classes when finished.  But, inline styles really aren't the problem here.

Comment: @user1060500 They are the problem here

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why.  Inline styles should work (and override CSS styles) according to every HTML CSS spec I have ever read.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I have converted everything to use CSS styles and have removed all inline styling and the result is the same.  No difference.  Problem exists.  Can you replicate it?

Comment: The result is in front of you, It is working for me, should work for you, and you are using inline styles but the property you are using is not meant for that tag, as well as it is not assigning height to table and td, it is applying to tr which doesn't make any sense

Comment: If the answer is there I don't see it.  I have revised my question to include my latest HTML source with removed inline styles and proper placement of height style.  If there is still something wrong here please explain, as I don't see the problem you are describing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25969/discussion-between-mr-alien-and-user1060500)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something on your page is triggering quirksmode, try setting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168288/page-stuck-in-quirks-mode)) or you may find some hints on [this page](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).

Comment: I updated my question with full HTML source and the problem exists still.  I am wondering if you can replicate it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it should work.Make sure there are no comments or any sort of code above the DOCTYPE declaration because that too makes IE go into quirks mode. Also add the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` just to be safe.

Comment: I updated my question with full HTML source and the problem exists still.  I am wondering if you can replicate it?