# jQuery, CSS change tag inside paragraph on HOVER

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Using jQuery I hover over a paragraph and have the paragraph change BG color and add a box shadow, easy. What I wish to add, however, is that when the paragraph's BG color changes (on hover), any `<strong>` tags in only that paragraph change their CSS to add emphasis. In other words, the default CSS for `<strong>` is off (no bolding):

CSS:

```
p.bullets strong
{
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

When the same paragraph hover occurs I wish only that paragraph's `strong` CSS change to:

```
p.bullets strong
{
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

jQ to change BG color, add shadow:

```
  $("p.bullets").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)')
  $(this).addClass('round_right boxShadow')
    }, function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', '')
       $(this).removeClass('boxShadow')
    });
```

HTML:

```
<p>We show parents and professionals <strong>dealing head-on</strong> with the issues that impact etc.</p>
```

---

The problem I'm having is getting the CSS change to affect only the one paragraph. All help appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: The good selector to manipulate `<strong>` when mouse is hover, is `p strong:hover` if you use CSS, and if you use jQuery `$('p strong:hover').each(function() {...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution:
Instead of `$(this).css('background-color', '')` use `$(this).find('strong').css('background-color', '')`.

A tip:

It's also better to use classes instead of direct styling with "css" with .addClass() and .removeClass().

```
p.bullets strong.hover
{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Then use that `.hover`:

```
$(this).find('strong').addClass('hover');
```

Same with removeClass().

Comment: SHould be ```$(this).find('strong').addClass('hover');```

Comment: What I wish to do is have the strong activated, in a sense, not when  strong is HOVER'd but when any part of its containing paragraph is.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why your using jQuery for this.

To change background on `P` hover

```
p.bullets:hover {
   background: #000;
   box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

To change the strong tag then:

```
p.bullets:hover strong {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Just an example. For supporting old browsers you can wrap your `p` in `a` and change css reflect this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <p class="bullets">Some text <strong> more text </strong> </p>
</a>

a:hover p.bullets {
   background: #000;
   box-shadow:0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

a:hover p.bullets strong {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Won't work in old browsers, that's why jQuery. Personally, I just don't care anymore and use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new css rule to catch strong tags inside the style you are already setting to the paragraph (assuming you are only using it here), otherwise add another class as well. Ex.:

```
p.bullets.boxShadow strong {
   /* your desired tag appearance */
   font-weight: 800;
}
```

Comment: Some IE don't like multiple classes.

Comment: Good call, but there seem to be workarounds for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671178/using-multiple-class-selectors-in-ie7-and-ie8 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select elements only in the current paragraph, add context parameter in your selector.

add this to on-hover function:

```
$("strong",this).css('font-weight','800')
```

and this to the out-hover function:

```
$("strong",this).css('font-weight','')
```